# При чтении данных из SQL считывается только первая строка

Tags: java, android, sql

Мне надо считать все данные из `SQL`. Но у меня всегда читается только первая строка.

**Код:**

```
    public ArrayList<Task> elementsHome(){
        ArrayList<Task> tempElements = new ArrayList<>();
        cursor = db.query(TABLE_HOME, null, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                Long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID));
                String task = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TASK));
                String comment = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_COMMENT));
                String dateString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DATE_STRING));
                Long dateStart = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DATE_START));
                Long dateFinish = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DATE_FINISH));
                ArrayList<Subtask> subtasks = elementsSubtask(task);
                tempElements.add(new Task(id, task, comment, dateString,
                        dateStart, dateFinish, subtasks));
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        Log.e("DEBUG", String.valueOf(tempElements.size()));
        return tempElements;
    }
```

Comment: Может while (!cursor.moveToNext());?

Comment: Нет, из-за этого вообще всё приложение падает

Comment: А что у нас в `elementsSubtask`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Именно в данном кусочке кода проблемы не видно. Нужен полноценный пример для воспроизведения.

Единственное, что смущает, так это то, что переменная `cursor` объявлена где-то вне метода. Подозреваю, что эта переменная используется в других методах, например, в `elementsSubtask`. Также подозреваю, что в других методах переменной присваивается новый курсор, который считывается до конца.

Предлагаю объявить `cursor` на уровне метода и посмотреть, что получится:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_HOME, null, null, null,
            null, null, null);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Именно так всё и было, я в `elementsSubtask` использовал тот же `cursor`.

Answer (score 0):

Как заметили выше предлагаю сделать чуток по другому

```
public ArrayList<Task> elementsHome(){
    ArrayList<Task> tempElements = new ArrayList<>();
    cursor = db.query(TABLE_HOME, null, null, null,
            null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            Long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID));
            String task = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TASK));
            String comment = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_COMMENT));
            String dateString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DATE_STRING));
            Long dateStart = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DATE_START));
            Long dateFinish = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DATE_FINISH));
            
            tempElements.add(new Task(id, task, comment, dateString,
                    dateStart, dateFinish, null));
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    // Идея считать подтаски отдельно вне курсора. Сделал setSubtasks в надежде что он существует 
    for(Task task: tempElements) { 
      task.setSubtasks(elementsSubtask(task.getName()));
    }
    Log.e("DEBUG", String.valueOf(tempElements.size()));
    return tempElements;
}
```